# iOS : BackbarButton

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I saw too many tutorial from stack overflow for how to change backBarButton I change it but when I check I see my image(custom arrow) beside (default arrow blue one ) I see both beside of each other
I mean the back text changed but the arrow doesn't I see my custom arrow beside default iOS arrow I don't know how should I change it to see my custom arrow only ???
for more detail please check this picture to see this problem
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkXfl.jpg)

Comment: you want to red arrow? then set tintcolor .

Comment: so if I want to add a custom arrow what should I do (imagine another arrow)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need to hide the default back Button , then supply your Custom one. Following code will help you.

```
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let back: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    back.setImage(UIImage(named: "backarrow"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    back.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 22, height: 22)
    back.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.backPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    let left: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: back)
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(left, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""

    func backPressed() {
      //Do your menupulation
    }
```

Comment: it will add it to firstViewController Than in next View controller Gone 1. I don't want to see in first view Controller 2. I won't be shown in second view controller

Comment: let me clarify u don't want to show the back button in all viewControllers ?? or u want to show only in second view controller .

Comment: how back button work normally (enable when you segue from first view controller) just change (< back) to my custom one (< custom arrow)

Comment: add this code in the second view controller where you segue or navigate. this will override the existing default back button and give your your custom button .

Comment: just for going back I will use dismiss function and if I had 3 view controller I will do the same at there in third view controller or more

Comment: yes, for custom you need to add your own logic, and if you have more then on viewController , you can manager stack of navigation and use stack to pop back to respective viewController.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You can set default back button color's tint color to red .

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red // add this line appdelegate
```

**Solution 2**

```
 self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

**or**

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[customBackButtonItem];
```

Comment: if I want to change arrow I should use second solution

Comment: yes you need to create custom buttom item and set to second solution

Comment: I want back button is this work for back button ?? I don't want custom one

Comment: you must set custom item button to back button if you want to customise in it .

Comment: for setting that I should drag and drop a bar button item

Comment: you can do through coding and storyboard

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question completely I don't want custom button (I only want to change back button) not other one

Comment: yes still not understand .. what is your expectation can you elaborate ?

Comment: I want to see only my (custom arrow image) instead this (< Back) not see this default for back button my custom picture (arrow)

Comment: I want my custom arrow (alone) just see my custom arrow nothing else thanks from paying attention to my question ;)

Comment: if you want to only your custom button then try my second solution. you can't understand it .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you just need to place your button into Navigation Bar and then set your image name into "image" field.
http://take.ms/Rfrtf - here is for example ;)